# Join data-frame based on value in list of WrappedArray

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to join two spark data-frames in Scala based on a custom function. Both data-frames have the same schema.

Sample Row of data in DF1:

```
{
  "F1" : "A",
  "F2" : "B",
  "F3" : "C",
  "F4" : [
               {
                "name" : "N1",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 50.0,
                "sf1" : "val_1",
                "sf2" : "val_2"
              },
              {
                "name" : "N2",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 100.0,
                "sf1" : "val_3",
                "sf2" : "val_4"
              }
         ]
}
```

Sample Row of data in DF2:

```
{
  "F1" : "A",
  "F2" : "B",
  "F3" : "C",
  "F4" : [
               {
                "name" : "N1",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 80.0,
                "sf1" : "val_5",
                "sf2" : "val_6"
              },
              {
                "name" : "N2",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 90.0,
                "sf1" : "val_7",
                "sf2" : "val_8"
              },
              {
                "name" : "N3",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 99.0,
                "sf1" : "val_9",
                "sf2" : "val_10"
              }
         ]
}
```

RESULT of Joining these sample rows:

```
{
  "F1" : "A",
  "F2" : "B",
  "F3" : "C",
  "F4" : [
               {
                "name" : "N1",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 80.0,
                "sf1" : "val_5",
                "sf2" : "val_6"
              },
              {
                "name" : "N2",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 100.0,
                "sf1" : "val_3",
                "sf2" : "val_4"
              },
              {
                "name" : "N3",
                "unit" : "none",
                "count" : 99.0,
                "sf1" : "val_9",
                "sf2" : "val_10"
              }
         ]
}
```

The result is:

- full-outer-join based on value of "F1", "F2" and "F3" +
- join of "F4" keeping unique nodes(use name as id) with max value of "count"

I am not very familiar with Scala and have been struggling with this for more than a day now. Here is what I have gotten to so far:

```
val df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("stack_a.parquet")
val df2 = sqlContext.read.parquet("stack_b.parquet")

val df4 = df1.toDF(df1.columns.map(_ + "_A"):_*)
val df5 = df2.toDF(df1.columns.map(_ + "_B"):_*)
val df6 = df4.join(df5, df4("F1_A") === df5("F1_B") && df4("F2_A") === df5("F2_B") && df4("F3_A") === df5("F3_B"), "outer")

def joinFunction(r:Row) = {
   //Need the real-deal here!
   //print(r(3)) //-->Any = WrappedArray([..])
   
   //also considering parsing as json to do the processing but not sure about the performance impact
   //val parsed = JSON.parseFull(r.json) //then play with parsed

   r.toSeq //
}
val finalResult = df6.rdd.map(joinFunction)
finalResult.collect
```

I was planning to add the custom merge logic in `joinFunction` but I am struggling to convert the WrappedArray/Any class to something I can work with.
Any inputs on how to do the conversion or the join in a better way will be very helpful.

Thanks!

### Edit (7 Mar, 2021)

The full-outer join actually has to be performed only on "F1".
Hence, using @werner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464793/1744480), I am doing:

```
val df1_a = df1.toDF(df1.columns.map(_ + "_A"):_*)
val df2_b = df2.toDF(df2.columns.map(_ + "_B"):_*)

val finalResult = df1_a.join(df2_b, df1_a("F1_A") === df2_b("F1_B"), "full_outer")
.drop("F1_B")
.withColumn("F4", joinFunction(col("F4_A"), col("F4_B")))
.drop("F4_A", "F4_B")
.withColumn("F2", when(col("F2_A").isNull, col("F2_B")).otherwise(col("F2_A")))
.drop("F2_A", "F2_B")
.withColumn("F3", when(col("F3_A").isNull, col("F3_B")).otherwise(col("F3_A")))
.drop("F3_A", "F3_B")
```

But I am getting [this](https://0bin.net/paste/q7awWm28#FzFLRtuLaN89TaBmOayZw1R-TMWzVkws4ms5SANdnf0) error. What am I missing..?

Comment: You have to add a null check to the inputs of the `joinFunction`. The stacktrace says that either `a` or `b` are null

Comment: Do you know how to add the null check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the merge logic with the help of an [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedFunction.html):

```scala
//case class to define the schema of the udf's return value
case class F4(name: String, unit: String, count: Double, sf1: String, sf2: String)

val joinFunction = udf((a: Seq[Row], b: Seq[Row]) =>
  (a ++ b).map(r => F4(r.getAs[String]("name"),
    r.getAs[String]("unit"),
    r.getAs[Double]("count"),
    r.getAs[String]("sf1"),
    r.getAs[String]("sf2")))
    //group the elements from both arrays by name
    .groupBy(_.name)
    //take the element with the max count from each group
    .map { case (_, d) => d.maxBy(_.count) } 
    .toSeq)

//join the two dataframes
val finalResult = df1.withColumnRenamed("F4", "F4_A").join(
  df2.withColumnRenamed("F4", "F4_B"), Seq("F1", "F2", "F3"), "full_outer")
//call the merge function
.withColumn("F4", joinFunction('F4_A, 'F4_B))
//drop the the intermediate columns
.drop("F4_A", "F4_B")
```

Comment: This is working when I use `Seq("F1", "F2", "F3")` as key for the outer-join but it breaks on `.collect` if I use `Seq("F1")` for the outer-join (refer [error](https://0bin.net/paste/q7awWm28#FzFLRtuLaN89TaBmOayZw1R-TMWzVkws4ms5SANdnf0) added in edit). Any thoughts on what I might be missing?